# Calculating probabilities of a meteor shower falling into a circle

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-distribution

A rain of meteors is falling on a circular area, with a radius of 10 km, so that each meteor is falling in a random place inside the area, without any dependancy on other meteor falls. assuming that the number of meteors that fall inside the round area is a poisson random variable with the parameter 2, and that the three assumptions of the poisson prccess are valid in the area where the meteors fall:

1)inside the 10km circle, we mark(create) another 6 km circle. if we know that inside of the  bigger circle(the 10 km one), 4 meteors exactly had fallen, what is the probability that exactly one of them fell inside the 6k inner circle?

2)assuming that the meteorite rain repeats itself 5 times, exactly as written, so there's no dependancy between its repititions, what are the odds that exactly 2 times (from the 5), at least 3 meteorites will fall inside the bigger circle?

how do you answer such a question? i'm lost, so i really don't know what to write or how to explain. using the formula of the poisson $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\gamma ^n e^{- \gamma}}{n!}$

i think that for the second question, we are looking for the case where p(x=3), which would've been easier,  but i don't know how to check  for at least 2 out of 5 times here, is it just a regular 2 out of 5 binom case?

just to clarify, the small circle(6km radius) is inside the bigger circle(10km radius)

Comment: Best to ask about one part at a time. What progress have you made thinking about (1)? Might help to consider inside and outside the 6km circle as being two independent processes. What is the rate of each?

Comment: solved the first one, struggling with the last

Comment: Then why not show engagement by giving your solution to (1)? At least that will let us know the level of your course and understanding of Poisson.

Comment: @BruceET: = $C(4,1) * 0.36 * 0.64^3$ gave me 0.377

Comment: I guess start by finding P(3 or more) in bigger circle in any _one_ of the five trials ('rains' of meteorites). Then use that as binomial $p$ with $n = 5.$ to finish. Once you get a start, hope someone writes it up as an answer.

Comment: did you get something like 0.324?